# Underscore.js: Sum of items in a collection

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I made a small plnkr [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/B5HGxhwvWsfvOR97z7TL?p=preview) to show what I am trying to achieve. I have a big dataset, where I like to sum the individual type to get a total.

I could think of iterating and adding the results to an object hash, but wonder more elegant way to solve it with underscore. I am using underscore.js, but never tried map reduce or other functional paradigm. Please update the plnkr to learn how to do this.

http://plnkr.co/edit/B5HGxhwvWsfvOR97z7TL?p=preview

```
var data = [ {'type': "A", 'val':2},
  {'type': "B", 'val':3},
  {'type': "A", 'val':1},
  {'type': "C", 'val':5} ];


 _.each(data, function (elm, index) {
   console.log(elm);  
 });

 /*
 Desired output

 out = [ {'type': "A", 'total':3},
  {'type': "B", 'total':3},
  {'type': "C", 'total':5} ];

 */
```

Answer (score 32, accepted):

```
var data = [ { type: "A", val: 2 },
             { type: "B", val: 3 },
             { type: "A", val: 1 },
             { type: "C", val: 5 } ];

var groups = _(data).groupBy('type');

var out = _(groups).map(function(g, key) {
  return { type: key, 
           val: _(g).reduce(function(m,x) { return m + x.val; }, 0) };
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/otucik/37/edit)

Comment: I suspect that the `groupBy` is going to introduce a fair bit of overhead in constructing all those arrays for a large data set

Comment: @Nevir sure its slower than creating hash (70% slower according to test), but I just like how groupBy is readable. With huge amount of data I'd definitely go with your solution, +1 from me

Answer (score 12):

Pretty much the same answer as @GregL, just with a bit more underscore:

```
summed_by_type = _(data).reduce(function(mem, d) {
  mem[d.type] = (mem[d.type] || 0) + d.val
  return mem
}, {})

pairs = _(summed_by_type).map(function(v,k) { return {type: k, total: v} })
```

Comment: Turns out your version is even faster than mine, I added it to my [jsPerf test](http://jsperf.com/summing-per-type). Using `reduce()` gives about 4.84 operations per second vs 3.5 ops/sec for my version.

Comment: That's surprising!  Your loop should be practically the same as the `reduce` call

Comment: Aha, it's the extra assignment on your loop: switching to a single assignment gets yours to slightly faster than the `reduce` call http://jsperf.com/summing-per-type/2

Answer (score 5):

The following will work, but I assume it is similar to what you had in mind. The advantage is that by using an object hash to store the totals, you are indexing on the type which means you don't have to iterate through the hash each time trying to find the object with the right type. Then you iterate through it once at the end to build up the final output array.

Plunkr is [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/z6fhMLU9rtvGhLgp5Dc4?p=preview).

Code is as follows:

```
var data = [ {'type': "A", 'val':2},
  {'type': "B", 'val':3},
  {'type': "A", 'val':1},
  {'type': "C", 'val':5} ];

var totalPerType = {};
for (var i = 0, len = data.length; i < len; ++i) {
  totalPerType[data[i].type] = totalPerType[data[i].type] || 0;
  totalPerType[data[i].type] += data[i].val;
}
var out = _.map(totalPerType, function(sum, type) {
  return { 'type': type, 'total': sum };
});

 console.log('out = ', out);
```

**EDIT:** I have created a new plunkr that generates how fast this is even for a 1 million item array (with 6 possible types) [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/z6fhMLU9rtvGhLgp5Dc4?p=preview). As you can see from the console output, at least in Chrome Canary, it runs in about 1/3 second.

I have also done a [jsPerf test](http://jsperf.com/summing-per-type) for how much faster it is to use the intermediate hash, and it works out about 50% faster.