# Reading OData contexts in onInit of controller

Tags: javascript, odata, sapui5

I've tried to prepare data from an OData source to show it in a bar graph in my fiori app. For this, I setup the OData model in the manifest.json. A test with a list, simply using

```
items="{path : 'modelname>/dataset'}
```

works fine and shows the content.

To prepare data for a diagram (VizFrame), I used the onInit() function in the controller of the view (mvc:XMLView). The data preparation is similar to the one discussed in [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24453439).

At first I obtain the ODataModel:

```
var oODataModel = this.getOwnerComponent().getModel("modelname");
```

Next I do the binding:

```
var oBindings = oODataModel.bindList("/dataset");
```

Unfortunately, the `oBindings().getContexts()` array is always empty, and also `oBindings.getLength()` is zero. As a consequence, the VizFrame shows only "No Data".

May it be that the data model is not fully loaded during the onInit() function, or do I misunderstand the way to access data?

Thanks in advance

**Update**
I temporary solved the problem by using the automatically created bind from the view displaying the data as list. I grep the "dataReceived" event from the binding `getView().byId("myList").getBindings("items")` and do my calculation there. The model for the diagram (since it is used  in a different view) is created in the Component.js, and registered in the Core `sap.ui.getCore().setModel("graphModel")`. 
I think this solution is dirty, because the graph data depends on the list data from a different view, which causes problems, e.g. when you use a growing list (because the data in the binding gets updated and a different range is selected from the odata model). 
Any suggestions, how I can get the odata model entries without depending on a different list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> May it be that the data model is not fully loaded during the onInit()
>   function, or do I misunderstand the way to access data?

You could test if your model is fully loaded by console log it before you do the list binding

```
console.log(oODataModel);
var oBindings = oODataModel.bindList("/dataset");
```

If your model contains no data, then that's the problem.

Comment: The console shows the model. E.g. under mContexts is a list of the first 20 entries from the oData, and aBindings contains an array with 81 objects (each of them has property sPath="/dataset").

Answer (score 2):

The following image outlines the lifecycle of your UI5 application.

[image]

Important are the steps which are highlighted with a red circle. Basically, in your `onInit` you don't have full access to your model via `this.getView().getModel()`.

That's probably why you tried using `this.getOwnerComponent().getModel()`. This gives you access to the model, but it's not bound to the view yet so you don't get any contexts.

Similarly `metadataLoaded()` returns a Promise that is fullfilled a little too early: Right after the metadata has been loaded, which might be before any view binding has been done.

**What I usually do is**

- use `onBeforeRendering`

This is the lifecycle hook that gets called right after `onInit`. The view and its models exist, but they are not yet shown to the user. Good possibility to do stuff with your model.

- use `onRouteMatched`

This is not really a lifecycle hook but an event handler which can be bound to the router object of your app. Since you define the event handler in your `onInit` it will be called later (but not too late) and you can then do your desired stuff. This obviously works only if you've set up routing.

Comment: This post answers more than the original question. Very valuable diagram, thank you. I moved the evaluation into the onBeforeRendering function.
But now I think, my problem is the binding itself. I have no bindings in the view itself. E.g. in a list I have something like `items="{path:'...'}` which automatically creates the binding. So maybe, the question is actually: How do I add such a binding manually to a view?

Comment: Please tell me, if I understand the chart right.
* In the init functio of the controller I add the listBinding to the data model (this seems to work, since the binding can be found in the debug output showing the model).
* In the "evaluation of the bindings" and "data retrieval" my binding should by filled with data, or?
* When the view get updated (function onBeforeRendering gets called?), I should have access to the data from the binding, e.g. gettings the contexts?

The binding created automatically by the list, the data is available, but not in the manually created one. Why?

Comment: I am not entirely sure why you need the contexts.. can you elaborate on that one?

Comment: The idea is, that I iterate through the data, count elements and create new data, which contains something like: on day X, in the hour between 1pm and 1:59pm, are Y elements with status 1. 
Maybe compare to the previously ask [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24453439/how-to-group-sapui5-odata-before-bind-to-control-at-client-side?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: Ah OK. If I want to fetch data I always use the `read` method. https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.model.odata.ODataModel.html#read You can provide filters and sorters similar to a binding, but it seems to be a more straight forward approach. The success function contains your data as a simple JS object.

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to wait until the models metadata has been loaded. Try this:

```
onInit: function() {
    var oBindings;
    var oODataModel = this.getComponent().getModel("modelname");
    oODataModel.metadataLoaded().then(function() {
        oBindings = oODataModel.bindList("/dataset");
    }.bind(this));
},
```

Comment: Thank you, I think this points into the right direction. But for understanding: When gets the function behind "then" executed? In my case, the metadataLoaded() function returns `[[PromiseStatus]]:"resolved"`, and oBindings is set? Is the metadataLoaded() function similar to the attachMetadataLoaded()?

Comment: I can not tell you exactly. I guess so. Try attachMetadataLoaded  :-)

Comment: I have now `oODataModel.attachMetadataLoaded(handler);` and it gets called. Inside the function of handler, the oODataModel has the property oMetadata->bLoaded: true, and also an oData object with the first 20 entries of my odata. But still, getContexts() is empty.

Comment: Is the event "dataReceived" not possible in the diagram view ?
You want to have 2 views, both List and Diagramm ?

Answer (score 0):

My basic misunderstanding was to force the use of the bindings. This seems to work only with UI elements, which organize the data handling. I switched to

```
oODataModel.read("/dataset", {success: function(oEvent) {
    // do all my calculations on the oEvent.results array
    // write result into graphModel
    }
});
```

This whole calculation is in a function attached to the requestSent event of the graphModel, which is set as model for the VizFrame in the onBeforeRendering part of the view/controller.