# underscore: group by date while calculating total of another field

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I have an array of objects of the following structure:

```
[{date: 08/17/15, total: 20}, {date: 08/17/15, total: 10}, {date: 08/15/15, total: 15}, {date: 08/14/15, total: 20}]
```

and I want to group the objects by the day while also totaling up the "total" fields of each object of that day. So for the above array, I want a result like:

```
[{date: 08/17/15, total: 30}, {date: 08/15/15, total: 15}, {date: 08/14/15, total: 20}]
```

currently, I am trying to use underscore to group the dates using something like this:

```
var groupedDates = _.groupBy(groupedValues, 'date', function(d) {
    return {
        date: d.date,
        total: d.total
    };
});
```

but am having trouble getting to totals to add up. Any help?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Underscore.js: Sum of items in a collection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14430321/underscore-js-sum-of-items-in-a-collection)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can solve it in pretty concise way with the help of reduce and find methods:

```js
var data = [{date: '08/17/15', total: 20}, {date: '08/17/15', total: 10}, {date: '08/15/15', total: 15}, {date: '08/14/15', total: 20}];

var result = _.reduce(data, function(prev, curr) {
    var found = _.find(prev, function(el) { return el.date === curr.date; });
    found ? (found.total += curr.total) : prev.push(_.clone(curr));
    return prev;
}, []);

alert(JSON.stringify(result, null, 4));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore-min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Reasonably [*performant*](http://jsperf.com/underscore-vs-pojs-array-stuff) too, but throws an error in Firefox